# I can drag my mouse over to my 2nd monitor while gaming

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

Just as the title says, I can drag my mouse over to my secondary monitor while playing *some* games. Not all games. For example, I am currently playing GTA 3 (practicing for a speedrun which makes everything 5x annoying) and I when I drag too far to the left, my cursor is showing on the other screen, but I am still in control of the camera ingame. If I then click, the game minimizes. Yes, I am running the game in fullscreen.

I have this problem when playing borderless (windowed fullscreen) in League of Legends aswell. But when I switch to "normal" fullscreen, it's fine.

I am also running Win7 64bit if that's any help.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: the only way to fix is for the game to lock on the cursor to the monitor on which it is being projected

Comment: Anyway I can do that? 'Cause the game doesn't seem to.

Comment: You can simply disable the second monitor if you want to avoid a software fix.  But programs should handle this on their own if they don't its a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to the game devs to implement the cursor lock so that the cursor doesn't go out of the current window - although you can use tools like [Actual Multiple Monitors](http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/) to lock the cursor to the current monitor.

I've used that feature succesfully quite a few times, so it should work.